# Routing problems from area to layout MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a routing problem from my "Equipe" area to the outside. I explain to us:

I have an area named "Equipe", i access from my layout on my main page:

_Layout.cs:

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="Home/Equipe">Equipe</a>
</li>
```

[image]

Once i click everything is good. i select another option inside this "Equipe" View so i get in this address which is working fine (controller inside my "Equipe" area) :

[image]

If i click on the Layout option "Equipe" i will like to see the "/Home/Equipe" page. Instead of this i have an error:

[image]

I guess is a problem on my routing (areas to the outside), but i don't have any idea how i should configure to redirect to the good view.

Here is my RouteConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

EquipeAreaRegistration.cs:

```
        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Equipe_default",
                "Equipe/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Can someone help me please? :) Thanks in advance the routing thing is still a little incomprehensible for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try changing your reference path as below..

```
<li class="nav-item">
 <a class="nav-link" href="~/Home/Equipe">Equipe</a>
</li>
```

Comment: this is working :) omg it was something so simple, thank you so much. Can you please explain me why it is working? I was suppossing than i should add a new route on my RouteConfig.cs ^^

Comment: ~ will act as root of the application, and from any page if you click on navigation link it should navigate you from the root. If it is working without any issues, please accept this as answer or let me know if any issues

Comment: Thank you so much it is clear for me! It is working :) +1